How can we select MUI Autocomplete option for different usage like include/exclude option?
We have a different requirement, such that user should be able to select an option (with or without exclude) using MUI Autocomplete. Below are the expectations:

if an option is clicked, by default it is "included"
however, user can choose to "exclude" an option by clicking on Exclude checkbox within each option. By excluding an option, the chosen option is added as Red Chip.
If user deletes an excluded Red chip, the option chip is then converted to included & color is changed back to default color -OR- If user deletes an excluded Red chip, the chip is cleared (i.e, default behavior)
the checkbox should represent the exclude state in each option (i.e, should be checked only if its excluded)
when included, the chip color is default
when excluded, the chip color is "Red"
the mui autocomplete can be (re-)populated with selected options (with/without exclude)

For this I created an extension of Autocomplete with custom "renderOption" & "renderTags", with a checkbox for each option. CSB link - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/n9g5ph

Thanks & regards,
